# Getting error while using hugging face transfomer

Tags: artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers, huggingface-tokenizers, huggingface, electrate

I am using the “google/electra-base-discriminator” model like below,

```
model = ElectraForPreTraining.from_pretrained(“google/electra-base-discriminator”)
tokenizer = ElectraTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(“google/electra-base-discriminator”)
```

but facing the below error:

> Unable to load weights from pytorch checkpoint file for
> 'C:\Users\Prajapati.Kishor/.cache\huggingface\hub\models–google–electra-base-discriminator\snaps
> hots\1b48ef100dac4676d84125a8a7b7ab7c51e00386\pytorch_model.bin’ at
> 'C:\Users\Prajapati.Kishor/.cache\huggingface\hub\models–google–electra-base-discriminator\sn
> apshots\1b48ef100dac4676d84125a8a7b7ab7c51e00386\pytorch_model.bin’.
> If you tried to load a PyTorch model from a TF 2.0 checkpoint, please
> set from_tf=True.

I also tried by using from_tf=True, like below:

```
model = ElectraForPreTraining.from_pretrained(“google/electra-base-discriminator”,from_tf=True)
tokenizer = ElectraTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(“google/electra-base-discriminator”,from_tf=True)
```

but I am facing the below issue:

> File “h5py\h5f.pyx”, line 106, in h5py.h5f.open OSError: Unable to
> open file (truncated file: eof = 45749007, sblock->base_addr = 0,
> stored_eof = 438200172)

I tried above things, but getting expected results.